# New-MailboxExportRequest don't work in remote PSsession

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

i often use the **New-MailboxExportRequest** 's command on an exchange server in powershell console, like this one :

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010;
New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox jadrego –filepath \\computer1\c$\test.pst -verbose
```

[image]

it works correctly. But if I run those commands in PS remote session like this one :
I use the same User (Domain Admin, Exchange Admin)

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName vdiv03 -ScriptBlock {
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010;
    New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox jadrego –filepath \\computer1\c$\test.pst
}
```

I obtain this error :

[image: ERROR]

```
failed to comunicate with mailbox database
```

with -verbose
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could translate the first part of the error since not everyone here can read / speak french.
Also please check if the user you are connected as has write access to the network share.

Comment: I use the same User (Domain Admin, Exchange Admin)

Comment: does it work if you execute the cmdlet in a normal powershell session on your target-computer?

Comment: I have try it in windows session on VDIV03 without Invoke-Command, it works (VDIV03 have cmdlet)

Comment: if mjolinor´s answer doesn´t solve the problem please run the command again with the -verbose parameter for more error info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading the snapin like that isn't supported in Exchange 2010.

IMHO, you'd be much better off just leveraging the native remoting built into Exchange for management tasks.

```
$ExchangeServer = <exchange serer name>

$SessionParams = 
@{
   ConfigurationName = 'Microsoft.Exchange'
   ConnectionURI     = "http://$ExchangeServer/powershell/"
   Authentication    = 'Kerberos'
  # Credential        = $Creds
}

$Session = New-PSSession @SessionParams

Invoke-command -ScriptBlock {New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox jadrego –filepath \\computer1\c$\test.pst} -Session $Session

Remove-PSSession $Session
```

Set $ExchangeServer to the name of one of your Exchange 2010 servers.  The account will need to be a member of the necessary RBAC role for the function you're performing, and you can uncomment the Credential parameter and provide alternate credentials for the session if you need to.

This will also elimnatat the need to have the management tools installed on the computer that's running the script, and the associated headaches of keeping it patched to the same level as what's on the servers.

If you're working interactively, or running a script that uses many Exchange cmdlets you can add the session creation to your profile, and do an Import-PSSession and you'll have proxy functions for the Exchange cmdlets available locally that you can use the same as if you'd loaded the snapin.

```
Import-PSSsession $Session
```

Some caveates to be aware of:

When you use implicit remoting like this, the account of the credentiaals used to establish the session will determine what capablilities you will have.  What appear to be Exchange cmdlets added to the local session are actually proxy functions ( you can verify this using Get-Command).  This set of proxy functions is created dynamically by Exchange when you initially establish the session and will be customized according to the RBAC roles the account making the connection belongs to.  If it doesn't have permissions to perform given functions you will not get the proxy functions for those cmdlets, or functions may not have parameters for those functions.

The results you get back will not be the same as the same as the native objects returned if you used an EMS shell, or loaded the snapin.  They will be deserialized objects, which means they may be missing methods and will lose some fidelity compared to the native objects. There will be very few instances where this will be an issue, or cannot by worked around.

Also be aware that when you use implicit remoting, updates are made under the authority of an Exchange system account, not your credentials.  When you use the snapin, your account must have permission to update the Exchange properties stored in AD directly, and those changes will be logged in Windows audit logs (if enabled) as having been made by that account.  When you use implicit remoting they will be recorded as being done by the Exchange service account.  Exchange will record the details of the actual user account that made the request in it's admin audit log, and you can use Search-AdminAuditLog to find out when changes were made, and by who even if Windows audit logging is not enabled. If you use the snapin directly and do not have AD audit logging enabled you will lose that audit trail.

Comment: Add at the end : Remove-PSSession $Session

Comment: ok it work's, but I can't include function in -sciptBlock (and I need a big script with many Function(); )

Comment: See Get-Help Invoke-Command, and look at the -File parameter.  Also see the note about doing an Import-PSSession.  That would let you run the script locally. Once you do the Import-PSSession, any Exchange specific cmdlets get invoked in the remote session, and the results returned to the local session. You can also use Import-PSSession in a script.

Comment: I did not know import-session, but first tests are very interesting for me. please post an answer with it and i accept it ;-)

Comment: Done.  Let me know if you need a better explanation, but that should get you started.

Comment: I am getting the following error,
The term 'New-MailboxExportRequest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Is the account your using granted the Import Export Mailbox permission in RBAC? You only get cmdlets for the roles you're assigned.